# Create a new schema in a particular database

Tags: postgresql

I have a Postgres server with multiple databases (e.g DB1, DB2, DB3)

I need to create a schema sch1 in only DB2. How can I do that?

I have tried connect DB2, but it is not working

Answer (score 2):

Lets say the database we will be using called test, then we have to connect to the database first then create schema, example below

```
\connect test;
CREATE SCHEMA sch1;
```